# Is it possible to pass argument requested by inner commands of a linux bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I've created a bash script file to log into my GIT account like this:

```
cd /var/www/republishan
sudo -u www-data git pull
```

The "git pull" command requires a username and password. Is it possible to store this information in a file and pas that file to my bash script?
I can do this in windows command prompt like this:

```
script.bat < inputs.txt
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: If this really is a linux question, why `script.bat`?

Comment: Man please read the text! I've done what I want to do in linux, in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Make your git account run over `ssh` and use `ssh` public keys. It's a bit of a hassle but you will be glad when you've done it.

If you insist on using password authentication, I suggest you do `man gitcredentials`. You can provide your own password sourcing script. All this will do is demonstrate that the way to go is as per my first paragraph.